# How does R use square brackets to return values in a vector?

Tags: r

I came across a question like this: "retrieve all values less than or equal to 5 from a vector of sequence 1 through 9 having a length of 9". Now based on my knowledge so far, I did trial & error, then I finally executed the following code:

```
vec <- c(1:9) ## assigns to vec

lessThanOrEqualTo5 <- vec[vec <= 5]

lessThanOrEqualTo5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I know that the code `vec <= 5` would return the following logical

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So my question is, how does R use these logical to return the appropriate values satisfying the condition since the code would end up having a structure like this `vec[TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE]`?

Comment: R returns the values of a vector where the logical value is TRUE. So since the first 5 values are TRUE, the first five values are returned. You can subset a vector with logical or numeric values.

Comment: @MrFlick I tried supplying these logical inside the square brackets to achieve same target, but, it's obvious I couldn't do it.

Comment: You need to put the logicals into a vector. `vec[c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)]`

Comment: (Or `i <- vec <= 5` and then `vec[i]` will work fine too.)

Comment: The `help("[")` page is a little long because it also covers `[[` and `$` and covers behavior for vectors, matrices, arrays, and lists. But reading it you'll see that a vector can be indexed `vec[i]` and `i` can be (a) a numeric vector giving the index numbers you want to extract (or drop, in the case of negative index numbers), (b) a character vector with the names of the elements you want to extract (if `vec` has names), or (c) a logical vector of the same length as `vec` indicating `TRUE` to include or `FALSE` to exclude each element.

Comment: If you run `dput(vec <= 5)` you can see a copy/pasteable version of the vector. Values in R are "pretty" printed to the console so you can't just swap the output into code. That should look like what @GregorThomas suggested

Comment: There's also a discussion of this in the R Intro Manual: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-vectors

Comment: And in the case of (c) if you provide a logical vector of shorter length it will be "recycled" - repeated - until it reaches the full length. So you can get every other value in a vector by indexing it with `c(TRUE, FALSE)`, e.g., `(1:10)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`

Comment: Thank you greatly @GregorThomas, this clearly shows how ``R`` maps each element of the vector to the corresponding logical value to determine which is to be returned.